# Visual Studio 2012 : Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I've Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate on Windows 7 x64 machine. 
Today when I tried to run my WPF application I got this error : 
[image]

What's wrong ? What is remote debugging ? I just want to run my application.

I've also lunched "msvsmon.exe" but it didn't fix my problem. 

Restarting my machine was another way to get rid of this problem that I tried.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Project + Properties, Debug tab.  Make sure you got the Release configuration selected.  Untick the "Use remote machine" option.  It isn't that clear why you are trying to debug the Release build btw.

Comment: duplicate question please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320720/unable-to-start-debugging-visual-studio-2012

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320720/unable-to-start-debugging-visual-studio-2012

Comment: Uninstalling OpenVPN fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 x64, VS 2012

In my case, the Remote Debugging Monitor component was installed and the app was clearly configured to debug locally in settings.  This was a WinForms app upgraded from VS 2008, .NET 3.5.

Turns out it was the Windows Firewall.  By directly running:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe
```

A firewall dialog appeared where I could allow msvsmon.exe to run.  After a VS 2012 re-start, debugging (locally) was fine!

Answer (score 3):

I you are running Proxifier add a rule to route ::1   (IPV6 Loop-back)  Direct and not via the proxy.

[image: IPV6 Visual-Studio Debug Fix]

Comment: Maaan, I tried everything, ports, blah, but not this ::1 thing, THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It was because of some tunneling software on my computer: Proxifier.

If you run it, after then this error will appear when you hit F5. However, closing the `Proxifier` would not be enough! You should close it, then close the VS, after then, reopen the VS.

Answer (score 0):

Select 'Local Machine', when you run the application.  It seems like Remote Machine is selected for debugging.