# Unable to start debugging on the web server -- msvsmon.exe

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to debug an IIS site from visual studio. I have been getting this for the past 2hours. Can anyone help? Have you seen this before?

unable to start debugging on the web server. The microsoft visual studio remote debugging monitor(msvsmon.exe) does not appear to be running on the remote computer.
Please see help for assistance.

Comment: Do you have the remote debugging tools installed on your server? Is the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor running on the server? Did you follow the steps for [Setting Up Remote Debugging](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/vstudio?query=remote%20debugging%202012&Refinement=195&ac=3) for your version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Where do I see that please? Is it like a service? I have never observed this before.

Comment: It's on your server, of course. You can't just connect to any server you want and start debugging it. See the link I just added to my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks. The whole thing is on the same server. I will install the tool now. I am using VS2010

Comment: I don't think he is trying to connect to remote server, he is getting an error debugging locally.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was that I had the domain spelt wrong in my hosts file.

Comment: Same for me, forgot to add my Project Url to my hosts file.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who arrives here through searching for solutions, I've answered this in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20640708/1997837):

> Myself and several other developers have been trying to look for a
>   solution for this problem for about 3/4 hours as Visual Studio crashed
>   then this error would occur (twice in 2 days). I then suddenly (after
>   a lot of debugging and trying other suggestions and headbanging) I
>   somehow realised that the file which was highlighted had changed and
>   when I was trying to debug was not the MVC app project, once I changed
>   it to my project's one it then worked.
>
> Hope this helps and saves people from hours of pain!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=38184
u can find Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, the solution was to add Project Url to Hosts file

In visual studio go to 
Main Menu -> Project -> {project_name} Properties
or in Solution Explorer double click properties 
Under Properties tab to to "Web" and add Project Url, make sure you have this in you IIS binding

Go to %windir%\System32\drivers\etc in my case C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
open hosts file using a text editor
add 127.0.0.1  http://mywebsite
and save