# Debugging error in Visual studio

Tags: c#, debugging

This is my problem. When i click in the start button this message will be coming. I can't start my project.

Here is the print screen about the error:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: if you google your error there are tons of articles addressing it

Comment: Why don't you try using the 'HELP' button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to start debugging - Visual Studio 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320720/unable-to-start-debugging-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these links, and see if it can help

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164726.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf8k2h6a(v=vs.100).ASPX

http://devnet.kentico.com/Blogs/Petr-Svihlik/June-2013/Running-Visual-Studio-Remote-Debugger-in-Domain-En.aspx

[Unable to start debugging - Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320720/unable-to-start-debugging-visual-studio-2012)

I hopes it might help you

Answer (score 0):

You may find this helpful:- [Error: The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164726.aspx)

> When you try to do remote debugging, you might receive this error
>   message. **It means that Visual Studio could not find an instance of the
>   Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor on the remote computer.** The
>   Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor is required for remote
>   debugging to work.
>
> If you are trying to connect to an instance of the Visual Studio
>   Remote Debugging Monitor running under a different user account, you
>   have to tell the debugger the name of the instance of msvsmon.exe to
>   connect to, for example, user_name@computer.